# Swift Error "UIButton.currentTitle must be used from main thread only"

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I just followed this you tube tutorial from the following link:

URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiXvvL1wNUc

I cam across an error saying "UIButton.currentTitle must be used from main thread only"

Not really sure how to fix this as I am new to making apps, can anyone help me?

Greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

[image]

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class GenreButtonScreen: UIViewController {
    var musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer

    @IBAction func genreButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
            if status == .authorized {
                self.playGenre(genre: sender.currentTitle!)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        musicPlayer.stop()
    }

    @IBAction func nextButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        musicPlayer.skipToNextItem()
    }

    func playGenre(genre:String) {
        musicPlayer.stop()

        let query = MPMediaQuery()
        let predicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: genre, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyGenre)

        query .addFilterPredicate(predicate)

        musicPlayer.setQueue(with: query)
        musicPlayer.shuffleMode = .songs 
        musicPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [search on an error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=must+be+used+from+main+thread+only) before posting. There are many, many existing questions on this topic.

Comment: The error message already says what the problem is. You need to understand what the main thread is anyways if you ever want to become good at developing ios apps. I don't want to be rude, but I would never ever hire a developer who doesn't understand what "main thread" means, not even for a junior position.

Answer (score 4):

The MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization is an async call, and layout components only can be modified in the Main Thread. You should use this way:

```
 MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
    if status == .authorized {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { 
           self.playGenre(genre: sender.currentTitle ?? String()) 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi João! thanks for helping me out, i'm actually still getting some errors

Answer (score 0):

As the completion of `requestAuthorization` is in a background thread you need to embed any **UIKit** code inside the main queue like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
  self.playGenre(genre: sender.currentTitle!) 
}
```

---

```
@IBAction func genreButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
        if status == .authorized {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.playGenre(genre: sender.currentTitle!) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sh_Khan, thanks again for your help! I now have another issue saying "Value of type 'GenreButtonScreen' has no member 'playGenre'"

Comment: awesome @Sh_Khan! no more errors now. I tried to press a button in the app but in the output at the bottom, I got this message:    

2019-01-14 03:44:58.864341+1100 MusicPlayer[578:47542] [SDKPlayback] Failed to get a valid response. Resetting expectations.

Comment: @J.BAT the predicate may not return anything

Comment: try to print `print(query.items)`